# How to filter to get the value of a column is exactly some array after order by, Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The question is:
 List all of customer id that had their FIRST 3 GOJEK orders EXACTLY IN THE following sequence: First order is RIDE, second is CAR and third is FOOD

and the preview of table is:

[image]

I'm considering doing things like get the customers whose first order is RIDE, customers whose second order is CAR and customers whose thrid order is FOOD separately, and then intersect among them. But I ran out of ideas for querying on the second and third order type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I'm quite new to this platform and don't know how to make thing formatted

Comment: When editing, put an empty row before and 4 blanks first in each row. Or mark and click `{}`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more tips.)

Answer (score 6):

You would do:

```
select d.customer_no
from daily_order d
group by d.customer_no
having to_json_string(array_agg(order_type order by order_time limit 3)) = to_json_string(array['RIDE', 'CAR', 'FOOD']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got an error using this: Query error: Equality is not defined for arguments of type ARRAY<STRING> at [42:8]

Comment: @Jane . . . As with many things array-related in BigQuery, convert to a JSON string.  Some of the limitations on arrays are just baffling -- they cannot be used as `group by` keys or for comparison.